# Unable to get value of data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here it's my html code

```
<select class="changeOption">
 {% for dBoy in dBoyList %}
    <option value="{{dBoy.id}}" data-locid='{{dboy.location.id}}'
 {% endfor %} 
</select>
```

When i'm select any option from dropdown list it shows undefine

JQuery code

```
$( ".changeOption" ).change(function() {
    var locId = $(this).data("locid")
    alert("id:  "+locId);
});
```

Comment: In your jQuery, `$(this)` refers to the select, not the option.

Comment: Side note: Unless you're using `data` for other things later, using `data` just to access the value of a `data-*` attribute does a fair bit of extra work; just use `attr` instead. Of course, if you're actually using `data` for things in code you haven't shown, that wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to context of select element. you need to find selected option in it and then get the attribute:

```
$(".changeOption").change(function() {
  var locId = $(this).find(':selected').data("locid")
  alert("id:  "+locId);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just realized the `data` is in *his* code, comment should be directed at him.